# Fluxbox: Toggle RootMenu using Mouse1

Tags: fluxbox

On Debian Jessie and Fluxbox 1.3.5, the behaviour I am looking for is: Every time I click on desktop, if a RootMenu is not already there, one should be drawn. If a RootMenu is already there, it should disappear. For this purpose, I added this line to `.fluxbox/keys` file:

```
OnDesktop Mouse1 :If {Some Matches ((@Role="fluxbox-menu")} {HideMenus}  {RootMenu}
```

after commenting out other mouse related bindings.

However, pressing Mouse1 on the desktop produces no effect, log file is clean and if I bind RootMenu to some other keys simply using

```
OnDesktop Mouse3 :RootMenu
```

RootMenu does appears correctly (so, nothing wrong with that).

Any idea why this is happening? More importantly, does the `keys` file not permit this kind of "complex" behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Fluxbox keys should support this kinda of behaviour; however, I have noticed some irregularities when attempting complex actions as well. I have been able to get this to work by using the following:

```
OnDesktop Mouse1 :If {Matches (Name!=)} {RootMenu} {HideMenus}
```

While the matching pattern seems crude, it seems to work. I haven't had time to investigate why this work with Fluxbox, but I've just expected that checked properties are (not) set when the Fluxbox menu is active.

Hopefully this work for you (or a least a starting point). If you find a better condition pattern to apply, I'd be curious to see it.